SNS not publishing message to SQS
Using publishMessage() method, I am able to create dynamic topics, subscribing with dynamic queues, but sns not publishing messsage to sqs. What is the issues here?

    public void publishMessage(String topicName, String message) {
            String topicArn = createTopic(topicName);
            subSQS(topicArn, topicName);
            pubTopic(message, topicArn);
        }
    
        private String createTopic(String topicName) {
            CreateTopicResponse result = null;
            CreateTopicRequest request = CreateTopicRequest.builder()
                    .name(topicName)
                    .build();
    
            result = snsClient.createTopic(request);
            return result.topicArn();
        }
    
        private void pubTopic(String message, String topicArn) {
    
            PublishRequest request = PublishRequest.builder()
                    .message(message)
                    .topicArn(topicArn)
                    .build();
    
            PublishResponse result = this.snsClient.publish(request);
            log.info(result.messageId() + " Message sent. Status is " + result.sdkHttpResponse().statusCode());
        }
    
        private void subSQS(String topicArn, String queueName) {
            
            CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = CreateQueueRequest.builder().queueName(queueName).build();
            String queueUrl = sqsClient.createQueue(createQueueRequest).queueUrl();
    
            // Get the ARN of the SQS queue
            GetQueueAttributesRequest getQueueAttributesRequest = GetQueueAttributesRequest.builder()
                    .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .attributeNames( QueueAttributeName.QUEUE_ARN)
                    .build();
            GetQueueAttributesResponse queueAttributes = sqsClient.getQueueAttributes(getQueueAttributesRequest);
            String queueArn = queueAttributes.attributes().get(QueueAttributeName.QUEUE_ARN);
            
            try {
                SubscribeRequest request = SubscribeRequest.builder()
                        .protocol("sqs")
                        .endpoint(queueArn)
                        .returnSubscriptionArn(true)
                        .topicArn(topicArn)
                        .build();
    
                SubscribeResponse result = snsClient.subscribe(request);
                System.out.println("Subscription ARN: " + result.subscriptionArn() + "\n\n Status is " + result.sdkHttpResponse().statusCode());
            } catch (SnsException e) {
                System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }



Did you Give permission to the Amazon SNS topic to send messages to the Amazon SQS queue? This can be done by editing the Access Policy on the SQS queue.

how to do it throw the code @JohnRotenstein?

When calling createQueue(), you will need to pass a policy that permits access from the SNS Topic.
